# why doesn't df['column_name'].replace(a_value, np.nan) work?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

In my data, missing values were inputted as `1900`. I want to take those out in order not to screw my mean and other stats... I tried the following, it did nothing...

```
df['bd_year'] = df['bd_year'].replace(1900, np.nan)
```

I wrote the little function below, which works nicely. But I'd still like to understand why `df.replace()` did not change my data at all (no error message).

```
df['bd_year'] = df['bd_year'].astype(str)

def data_error (row):
    if row['bd_year'].startswith('1900'):
        return None
    return row['bd_year']

df['bd_year']=df.apply(lambda row:data_error(row), axis=1)
```

Comment: BTW: `lambda row:data_error(row)` => just `data_error`. No need for lambda here

Comment: you would have to check what you have in cells. Maybe you already have strings "1900" and you should use string in `.replace("1900", np.nan)`

Comment: Could you please include a sample of your data for quicker execution? Just copy and paste df.head() output.

Comment: You may want to check your data type on the 'bd_year' column. I just ran the df['bd_year'] = df['bd_year'].replace(1900, np.nan) code and it worked just fine. Just use df.dtypes. If it's int64 this should work. If it's an object, then you need to enclose 1900 in quotes.

Comment: Thanks @furas it was indeed that the data was in str !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`startswith` is a function that you run on strings, which means that the datatype must be a string (object in this case). Therefore, you have to put quotes around the query:

```
df['bd_year'] = df['bd_year'].replace("1900", np.nan)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df[['HCVVirus','BloodTransfusion','Hemodialysis','Syringers']] = df[['HCVVirus','Hemodialysis','BloodTransfusion','Syringers']].replace(0,np.NaN)
```